# What is the shortest way to create a record form list?

Tags: haskell, record

Suppose I have record definition

```
data Zone = Zone
  { zId      :: Int -- this zone's ID
  , zOwnerId :: Int -- the player who owns this zone (-1 otherwise)
  , zPodsP0  :: Int -- player 0's PODs on this zone
  , zPodsP1  :: Int -- player 1's PODs on this zone
  , zPodsP2  :: Int -- player 2's PODs on this zone (always 0 for a two player game)
  , zPodsP3  :: Int -- player 3's PODs on this zone (always 0 for a two or three player game)
  } deriving Show
```

What is the shortways to create record from `[String]` read from `getLine`

```
zones <- replicateM zoneCount $ fmap (mkZone . words) getLine
```

This is the best I can do so far.

```
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}

mkZone :: [String] -> Zone
mkZone xs = Zone {zId, zOwnerId, zPodsP0, zPodsP1, zPodsP2, zPodsP3}
  where [zId, zOwnerId, zPodsP0, zPodsP1, zPodsP2, zPodsP3] = map read xs
```

I use this pattern a lot when playing codingame [bot programmings](https://www.codingame.com/multiplayer/bot-programming), It would be nice if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`RecordWildCards`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#record-wildcards) removes half of your boilerplate.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}

mkZone :: [String] -> Zone
mkZone xs = Zone {..}
  where [zId, zOwnerId, zPodsP0, zPodsP1, zPodsP2, zPodsP3] = map read xs
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with SYB, like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Data
import Control.Monad.State

data Zone = Zone { zId, zOwnerId, zPodsP0, zPodsP1, zPodsP2, zPodsP3 :: Int }
    deriving (Show, Data)

main = do
    print (mygread ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"] :: Maybe Zone)
    print (mygread ["a", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"] :: Maybe Zone)
    print (mygread ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"] :: Maybe Zone)

mygread :: forall a . Data a => [String] -> Maybe a
mygread = evalStateT (fromConstrM read' constr)
  where
    constr = head . dataTypeConstrs . dataTypeOf $ (undefined :: a)
    read' :: forall a . Data a => StateT [String] Maybe a
    read' = do
        x:xs <- get
        put xs
        lift . fmap fromConstr . readConstr (dataTypeOf (undefined :: a)) $ x
```

Output:

```
Just (Zone {zId = 1, zOwnerId = 2, zPodsP0 = 3, zPodsP1 = 4, zPodsP2 = 5, zPodsP3 = 6})
Nothing
Nothing
```

You only need to make your type an instance of Data (`deriving Data`).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I’d go for `RecordWildCards` and call it a day. But here’s another hackish-but-interesting way to do this, which may be useful in some circumstances: throw caution to the wind and use dynamic types to get a type-changing fold!

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Dynamic (dynApp, fromDynamic, toDyn)
import Data.List (foldl')
import Data.Typeable (Typeable)

-- Add the 'Typeable' instance to enable runtime type information.
data Zone = Zone
  { zId, zOwnerId, zPodsP0, zPodsP1, zPodsP2, zPodsP3 :: Int
  } deriving (Show, Typeable)

mkZone :: [String] -> Maybe Zone
mkZone = fromDynamic . foldl' dynApp (toDyn Zone) . map (toDyn . readInt)
  where

    -- This type-specialised 'read' avoids an ambiguous type.
    readInt :: String -> Int
    readInt = read
```

This starts from the `Zone` constructor, of type:

```
Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Zone
```

Then applies it successively to each `Int` read from the input, changing its type:

```
Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Zone
Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Zone
Int -> Int -> Int -> Zone
Int -> Int -> Zone
Int -> Zone
Zone
```

And it works:

```
> mkZone ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
Just (Zone {zId = 1, zOwnerId = 2, zPodsP0 = 3, zPodsP1 = 4, zPodsP2 = 5, zPodsP3 = 6})
```

If you supply too few arguments, you get `Nothing` because the runtime cast fails:

```
> mkZone ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
Nothing
```

However, if you supply too *many* arguments, you get an exception:

```
> mkZone ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
*** Exception: Type error in dynamic application.
Can't apply function <<Zone>> to argument <<Int>>
```

That’s easily fixed by using `dynApply` instead of `dynApp`, which returns a `Maybe` instead of throwing. And as long as you’re working in `Maybe`, you might as well use `Text.Read.readMaybe` to handle parse errors:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Control.Monad ((<=<))
import Data.Dynamic (Dynamic, dynApply, fromDynamic, toDyn)
import Data.List (foldl')
import Data.Typeable (Typeable)
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

data Zone = Zone { … } deriving (Show, Typeable)

mkZone :: [String] -> Maybe Zone
mkZone = fromDynamic <=< foldl' go (Just (toDyn Zone)) . map readInt
  where

    go :: Maybe Dynamic -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Dynamic
    go mAcc mx = do
      acc <- mAcc
      x <- mx
      dynApply acc $ toDyn x

    readInt :: String -> Maybe Int
    readInt = readMaybe
```

For real though, probably don’t do this.